# Usar resultado de uma consulta SQL como atributo a outra consulta.(MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
tabela (Grupo):
-cd_grupo
-nm_grupo
-ds_filtros -> Aqui armazeno parte do comando SQL utilizado como filtro , para posteriormente atualizar.
```

Armazeno as seguintes informações.

```
cd_grupo  |   nm_ grupo  |   ds_filtro
   1      |    grupo1    | AND (uf = 'PR') AND (genero = 'F')
   2      |    grupo2    | AND (nasc >= '1990-02-20')
```

existe uma outra tabela de vinculo, onde vinculam os funcionários de acordo com o filtro do grupo.

```
cd_grupo  |   cd_funcionario
   1      |        14
   1      |        19
   1      |        35
```

minha duvida é preciso atualizar a tabela vinculo quando muda o status do funcionário e quando é inserido funcionario novo.

Desta forma abaixo sei que não funciona mas a ideia seria esta:

```
SELECT cd_funcionario FROM funcionario WHERE (SELECT ds_filtros FROM grupo)
```

Que iria trazer os filtros "AND (uf = 'PR') AND (genero = 'F')"  e adicionar depois da clausula WHERE

Tem alguma alternativa de como armazenar os filtros ou se desta forma tem como buscar todos os filtros na tabela grupo e aplica-los em um outro comando SQL seja ele REPLACE, UPDATE ou INSERT ?

estou utilizando PHP com Mysql.

Comment: no caso a ideia é armazenar o comando, não resultados?

Comment: pelo que entendi e so vc salvar o resultado em uma variável e depois colocar essa variável apos o WHERE

Comment: isso , eu armazeno os comando utilizados no respectivo filtro

Answer (score 0):

tenho um exemplo que ja fiz uma fazes, então o seu vai ficar mas ou menos assim
no meu banco tem 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
ai ele mostra 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <?php
    $host ="localhost";
    $usu="root";
    $senha="";
    $bd="ts";
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $usu, $senha, $bd);
        $sql="SELECT `numero` FROM `ts` WHERE id=1";
        $execut=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        while($row= MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY($execut)){
                $filtro=$row['numero'];
        }
        $sql="SELECT `numero` FROM `ts` WHERE $filtro";
        $execut=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        while($row= MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY($execut)){
                $filtro=$row['numero'];
        }
        echo $filtro;
    ?>
```

Comment: tinha pensado desta forma, será que usando TRIGGERS direto no MYSQL teria alguma forma ?

Comment: Nota https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/